# Restricted user error with connection to localhost closed by remote host

Tags: shell, ssh, ksh, aix

I'm trying to set sftpuser restricted by ChrootDirectory on AIX7.1. But it's not working and shown "connection to localhost closed by remote host"
Now, I configurated in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Match User testuser 
  ChrootDirectory /Share
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

The /Share owner by root user and permission is 755 but it's still not working and show debug as below.

```
sftp -vvv testuser@localhost

OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019

debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to localhost ([127.0.0.1]:22).
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to localhost closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 2256, received 2228 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 270661.7, received 267302.4
debug1: Exit status -1
Connection closed
```

How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This sounds like it would fit better at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You should debug on server-side: start sshd in verbose/debug mode on a different port.